# iOS - Is it possible to use EventKit library but not saving any data to the database(at least not showing in any calendar app)

Tags: ios, objective-c, calendar, eventkit

I have an array of event data entries loaded from server. And I think it can be handy if I can use EventKit lib to handle stuff such as event recurrence. But I don't want to make my events to be global events(it probably means saving to the calendar database), which will be showing on all calendar apps. Instead I just want my events to be accessed only inside my app.

Is this achievable?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I would implement the NSCoder protocol on EKEvent, which will then allow you to store your array when the app is terminated and restore it when it loads. There are already various github projects that will do this for you (e.g. https://github.com/yep/DeviceSync-for-iOS/blob/master/DeviceSync/Categories/EKEvent%2BNSCoder.h).

The alternative is to use core data, but you'd have to take care of mapping all of EKEvent's properties into database entities and attributes yourself.

Comment: Thanks norders, will I be able to get all EKEvents from the event store. e.g. will the following code still work?

NSArray *events = [self.eventStore eventsMatchingPredicate:predicate];

Comment: That will return the user's current calendar events, so yes. The user will be asked if they want to allow your app access or not. If you want to run predicates on your own internally held array of events use "[myEventArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:]". Just to mention your internally held array of events won't actually have any calendar functionality (e.g. reminders, syncing, etc). You'll need to deal with that yourself.

Comment: I think I might not explain it well. I don't want to attach additional data to EKEvents, instead, I want to create and use them as normal EKEvents with one exception - which is not saving to the database so it's only available inside my app and user won't see it at all in Calendar app.